# Structure of api versioning system in PHP

Tags: php, yii, kohana

So I want to add backward in-compatible changes to my API.

I was thinking of doing the following.

All of my api endpoints are accessed as follows:

```
/v2/account
/v2/order
```

Having a v2 controller that is passed an API version and calls the appropriate function in version specific controllers that are subclass to v2.

so for version 2013_02_13 it calls `v2_2013_02_13::account` for account api call

How would you implement an API versioning system to support backward incompatible changes using a PHP mvc framework?

Comment: Hey, So how did you implement it? I am using Symfony2 and looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Kohana you could just use a directory for that. So your controllers would be placed like this.

`application/classes/Controllers/V2_2013_02_13/Enpoint1Controller`

Than you can set up routes for your different versions.

```
Route::set('v2', 'v2/<controller>(/<action>)')
->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'V2_2013_02_13',
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

This would be the most easy approach, however if you really want to have some dynamic way to call specific versions of your controllers than I would look at the HMVC of Kohana.

My guess would be, that you need an entry controller for each version you have and do an internal request to the correct controller.

Maybe something like this.

Route:

```
Route::set('versioned', '<version>/<someAction>')
->defaults(array(
    'version'        => 'v2',
    'someAction'     => 'user'
    'controller'     => 'welcome',
    'action'         => 'index',
));
```

Controller:

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        // Your Version and the action
        $this->request->param('version');
        $this->request->param('someAction');

        // Do an internal request to the right controller (the v2/user is an example)
        $internalRequest = Request::factory('v2/user');
    }

}
```

I hope this helps.